# Symfony - dynamically add file form field

Tags: javascript, php, symfony

I'm trying to dynamically add file field to form in symfony 2 using js and `PRE_SUBMIT` event listener. That's what I've got:

JS:

```
function addFileField() {
    var container = document.getElementById("files");
    var new_file_field = document.createElement("input");
    new_file_field.type = "file";
    new_file_field.onclick = function() { addFileField(); };
    new_file_field.id = "order_file" + getFileFieldsCount().toString();
    new_file_field.name = "order[file" + getFileFieldsCount().toString() + "]";

    container.appendChild(new_file_field);
}
```

Where `getFileFieldsCount()` simply returns how many file fields there's been created so far.

And in my listener for `PRE_SUBMIT` I simply have:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $data['files_count']; $i++ ) {
    $form->add("file$i", 'file');
}
```

Where `files_count` is a hidden field which value contains what `getFileFieldsCount()` returns when clicking submit button. The only problem is that form data contains only filename of the file that is supposed to be uploaded, not the file itself. I am trying to make it work for couple hours now, can someone help?

Comment: I don't know if you need to use the `PRE_SUBMIT` event. I think all you need is to read [this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html) article.